# how to change macro ID using another macro

Tags: c

I was writing an implementation of dynamic arrays in C and I came across the fact that there are no generic types in C. To solve this problem, I came up with the following macro construction:

```
#define arr_type int

//#include "array.h"

#define arr_template(name, type) arr_ ## name ## _ ## type
#define arr_func(...) arr_template(__VA_ARGS__)

arr_type arr_func(init)(long long int len){
    /...
}
#undef arr_type
```

However, I have `#ifndef ARRAY_H` and `#define ARRAY_H` written in the header files, which exclude re-compilation, and after I made the “generic” types, I needed to create a macro like

```
#define ARRAY_(arr_type)_H
```

where instead of `(arr_type)` the macro `arr_type` is substituted. How can I do it?

Comment: It's not possible to define or test a dynamic macro name. See the linked question for more details.